# How to make such kind of table on html?

Tags: html

So I had an assignment but I cant really make such table:

[image: sample]

Comment: Look for the colspan attribute of <th> and <td> to "merge" two adjacent cells

Answer (score 2):

You have to use rowspan and colspan to merge cells

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Name<br></th>
    <th rowspan="2">Course</th>
    <th colspan="2">hours<br></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>credit</td>
    <td>contact</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aa</td>
    <td>bb</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cc</td>
    <td>dd</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro! I appreciate it !